# $eval failed to select inside foreach loop

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a code where I need to execute $eval inside foreach loop but it is not working, it is throwing an error that item.$eval is not a function.

however "items" its created successfully without issues

```js
let items = await newPage.$$eval('.slide', el => el);

items.forEach(async (item) => {

    let ProductName = '';
    try {
        ProductName = await item.$eval('.name', el => el.innerText);
    } catch (error) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Argument in [`page.$$eval()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) function is an array of elements. You just return this array of elements from browser context to Node.js context, but since DOM elements are not serializable, you just get an array of empty objects, which have not `.$eval()` method.

You can use [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) instead to get an array of ElementHandles. Also, it is better to use for-of loops with async functions instead of `.forEach()` to make the flow more predictable:

```js
let items = await newPage.$$('.slide');

for(const item of items) {
    let ProductName = '';
    try {
        ProductName = await item.$eval('.name', el => el.innerText);
    } catch (error) {
    }
}
```